# Javascript Date object from Java backend

Tags: javascript, java, rest, date, asynchronous

I'm currently working with a REST architecture to transfer data from a Java backend to a JavaScript based frontend.

The backend data is directly used by a frontend framework which requires JS Date objects.

Is it possible to create a object in Java that I can pass to the frontend and that fulfills the function as JS Date object?

When I try to just pass the string of the date and convert it to JS Date objects in a foor-loop, I get trouble with the asynchronous property of JS. (The framework uses the data before it went trough the for-loop).

The data is a simple array with dates as strings at the moment.

```
JiraService.getDailyReleaseJiraDates().then(function success(ganttReleases) {

                var DATA = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                DATA.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
                DATA.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
                DATA.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
                DATA.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
                DATA.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
                DATA.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
                DATA.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
                DATA.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

                for(var i = 0; i < ganttReleases.size; i++) {
                    ganttReleases[i] = new Date(ganttReleases[i]);
                    ganttReleases[i] = new Date(ganttReleases[i]);
                }
                        DATA.addRows(ganttReleases);
                        var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                        chart.draw(DATA, options);
```

So either I create the Date objects in the Java backend or I create the objects in the JavaScript frontend a shown in the code (what currently doesn't work because of async properties of JS).

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question and provide codes? Like your code for the backend, the data you are passing, and how you receive it in the js front end.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.
Usually we convert the java objects into `String`-s, then the the browser creates their own objects from those `String`-s. Some shiny frameworks like Tapestry or gwt are hiding it from you. Anyway, this is what's happening under the hood.

Comment: "The framework uses the data before it went trough the for-loop" Is it you making the REST call or that framework? If it is the framework, then there must be a way to send Date objects in a way it understands. If it is you, you can transform the result into the format the framework understands before handing it off.

Comment: I edited my question and added code.

Comment: Why doesn't this work because of "async properties"? Are you sure `DATA` is correct after your transformation?